# Printing a string character-by-character

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char a[]={"Hello"};
    while(a!='\0') {
        printf("%c",*a);
        a++;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Strings are stored in contiguous memory locations & while passing the address to printf() it should print the character. I have jst started learning C. I am not able to find an answer to this. Pls help.

Comment: The first problem is your title. It's not informative, please edit it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: Not really an exact duplicate of the question but you are trying to use an array as if it were a pointer so I believe that the answer to the linked question should also answer your question.

Comment: `man putc`, `man fputc`  Using `printf` to print a single character is  not wrong, but a bit strange.

Answer (score 5):

Well `a` is the name of the array which you cannot increment. It is illegal to change the address of the array.

So define a pointer to `a` and then increment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int i;
     char a[]="Hello";
     char *ptr = a;
     while(*ptr!='\0')
     {
         printf("%c",*ptr);
         // a++ here would be illegal
         ptr++;
     }
     getch();
     return 0;
 }
```

`NOTE:`

In fact, arrays in C are non-modifiable `lvalues`. There are no
  operations in C that can modify the array itself (only individual
  elements can be modifiable).

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `a` is a name of an array, you can't modify it like `a++`. Use a pointer like this:

```
char *p = "Hello";
while(*p++)
{
     printf("%c",*p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. `char a[]={"Hello"};` is illegal. `{"Hello"}` can only initialize `char* a[]`. You probably want `char a[]="Hello";`
2. `while(a!='\0')` - you probably meant `*a != '\0'`. `a` is the array itself.
3. `a++;` - an array cannot be incremented. you should increment a pointer pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it using a for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char a[] = "Hello";
   char *p;

   for(p = a; *p != '\0'; p++) {
      printf("%c", *p);
   }

   return 0;
}
```